# Neighm my bicycle

Tags: identify-this-bike, april-fools

I recently saw a very interesting motorized bicycle on the internet and was hoping someone could help me identify it.

[image]

If it helps, here's the serial number:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You're about 5 hours too early for this.

Comment: @whatsisname I was going to wait, but since Criggie posted his already, I couldn’t let him get all the attention…also it’s April 1 in some places already :)

Comment: Dang timezones - how do they work ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the day is over.   Great title though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**POWER**

Well, its definitely under the maximum power limit for pedal-assisted bicycles in all the world where Wattage matters.

https://www.haggardhawks.com/post/donkeypower   suggests that one donkey can put out "a third of a horsepower"

1 Horsepower is 746 Watts so a third of that is about 250 Watts.  This makes your suggested rig legal for road usage.

---

**EMISSIONS**

You may need to periodically clean up any emissions too - earlier models like this are known for methane production under operational conditions.

---

**DIMENSIONS**

Your suggested ebike might be too long depending on local laws, and could also be too heavy.

> The average Donkey has an overall height of 43”-57” (109-145 cm), withers height of 36”-48” (92-123 cm), and body length of 57”-76” (145-193 cm). A typical Donkey weighs between 400-500 lb (180-225 kg)
> <sub>Source: https://www.dimensions.com/element/donkey-equus-africanus-asinus</sub>

Approximate scaling on the above image returns a total length of between 3 and 4 metres.  While less than most cars, you'll need to check your local laws.

Additionally, some facilities like bridges and culverts may have load maximums.  A bike of 200+ kilograms plus the saddle plus one or two riders may exceed these rated maximums.  Check first !

---

**SERIAL NUMBER**  Now here's some confusion - this inscription dates from the 20th Egyptian Dynasty and weighs 215 kilograms on its own.   This additional mass contributes to the previous section.

The inscription itself contains "2 horizontal lines containing the prenomen and nomen of Ramses III." The name is also called the Cartouche which are the two areas inside ovals.  The name is repeated on the other end, but mirrored.  The bird wings over the top are decorative, and not part of the wording.   Clearly this bike was owned by a famous celebrity,  the last great monarch who reigned from 26 March 1186BC to 15 April 1155BC, Ramses III (also written Rameses III and variations)

> This dynasty is generally considered to be the start of the decline of Ancient Egypt.

Clearly their bicycles weren't optimised for aero, but if the serial is authentic then this bike is over **3100 years old**.
 Clearly the wheels are solid or metal, given that pneumatic tyres wouldn't be invented till Robert William Thomson patented his pneumatic tire in 1845AD, and Dunlop came up with improvements applied to Bicycles in 1895AD.

Comment: Actually, those tires seem to be pneumatic - Are you sure the serial number plate is not counterfeit? If it's legit, the bicycle seems to have been maintained/modded/tuned rather aggressively by its previous owners to the point where I doubt that any piece of original bike is left at all.